# not supported on CPU; using FP32 instead warnings.warn("FP16 is not supported on CPU; using FP32 instead") Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python, openai-whisper

I created a tool to convert a video file to audio and then use Whisper to extract the speech as text then using google translate to translate the generated text to the desired language, i have a Ryzen 7 7800x3d and nVidia RTX 2080 Ti. the code works like a charm on my system, however, on my laptop with Intel Core i7 5600U, i get this error

not supported on CPU; using FP32 instead warnings.warn("FP16 is not supported on CPU; using FP32 instead") Traceback (most recent call last):

here is my full code

```
import os
import moviepy.editor as mp
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from googletrans import Translator  


text_file_path = ""


def convert_and_extract_text():
    global text_file_path  

    video_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select a video file")

    if video_file:
        os.environ["IMAGEIO_FFMPEG_EXE"] = r'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\ffmpeg-full\tools\ffmpeg.exe'
        audio_file = os.path.splitext(video_file)[0] + ".mp3"

        video = mp.VideoFileClip(video_file)
        video.audio.write_audiofile(audio_file)

        print(f"Video converted to MP3 with the same name as the video: {audio_file}")

        whisper_command = f'whisper "{audio_file}" --model medium'
        subprocess.run(whisper_command, shell=True)

        print("Text extraction completed.")

        
        text_file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(audio_file))[0] + ".txt")


def browse_and_translate_text():
    global text_file_path  

    if text_file_path:
        status_label.config(text="Translating...")  

        
        with open(text_file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            text_to_translate = file.read()

        
        translator = Translator()

        
        translated_text = translator.translate(text_to_translate, src="en", dest="ku")

        
        translated_file_path = os.path.splitext(text_file_path)[0] + "_ku.txt"
        with open(translated_file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            file.write(translated_text.text)

        status_label.config(text="Translation completed.")  
    else:
        status_label.config(text="Text file not found. Make sure text extraction is completed.")  


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x200")


background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="kurdistan.gif")


background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_image)
background_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)  


background_label.photo = background_image


browse_button = tk.Button(root, text="Browse Video File", command=convert_and_extract_text)
browse_button.pack()


status_label = tk.Label(root, text="", fg="green")
status_label.pack()


translate_button = tk.Button(root, text="Browse Text and Translate", command=browse_and_translate_text)
translate_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I tried some solutions but still no luck. can someone please look into the code and suggest some modifications?